# Where to change the text on the CHECKOUT login page (STEP1)?

Tags: magento-1.9

I´ve tried to modify some text in several different files but it does not seem to reflect where I need to change it....I am trying to change/add some text to the **CHECKOUT page STEP 1** where it says:

> CHECKOUT AS A GUEST OR REGISTER

and

> LOGIN
>
> Already registered?
>
> Please log in below:
>   *Email Address

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be located in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`.

Although if you are using Persistent, the following is loaded: `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`

In any case, if you are looking for a template file, turning on `Path Hints` can be really helpful.
http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints